# How to solve this issue in objective C in iOS app development,?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

**Given in comment, where counterData is another mutableArray**
**I am sending data from watch to ios using openParentApplication**
**but at vc.counterData the app is getting crashed**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)  (NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
{       
     NSString *counterValue = [userInfo objectForKey:@"counterValue"];

        reply(@{@"insert counter value":counterValue});
        if (!self.tempCounterData)

        {
            self.tempCounterData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }

        [self.tempCounterData addObject:counterValue];

        //Add the new counter value and reload the table view
        AppDelegate *tmpDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication   sharedApplication] delegate];

        ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)  ((UINavigationController*)tmpDelegate.window.rootViewController).visibleViewController;

        vc.counterData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.tempCounterData copyItems:YES];//app crashing at this point, copying one array to another
        [vc.mainTableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: are you sure vc.mainTableView is loaded at this time?

Comment: nope not sure about I guess this is the problem for app crashing, please help how to solve this? Put I put the breakpoint at vc.counter its crashing there only once I am sending the data from watch extension.

Comment: Please add a short title and put your question in the description :)

Comment: If it crashes, what's the error message?

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance, this is the error

Comment: Please copy the exact error and paste it into your question.  It's easier to analyze the real thing than a description of it.

Comment: Also, try using NSLog() to display the value of `vc`.  With the way you're retrieving it, it would be nice to know if it really is a `ViewController *`.